# Theorem of Complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm having trouble finding a proof of this basic theorem:

Let $G$ be a region and let $f$ be analytical function in $G$. Then there is an analytic function $F$ such that $F'(z)=f(z) \forall z \in G$.

The theorem's name should be "Existence of a complex antiderivative".

Comment: I would hazard a guess that it is an incomplete definition of a primitive.

Comment: @copper.hat $\mathbf C^\times$ is a region (open connected, I suppose that's what you mean?)

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: You are correct, I should have written a simply connected region.

Answer (score 3):

That's not true. Consider $z^{-1}$ in $\mathbf C^\times$. It's true if you ask $G$ to be simply connected, for example, though it might still hold -- consider $z^{-2}$ in the punctured plane. In fact, it is a theorem that if *every* $f\in \mathcal O(G)$ has a primitive, then $G$ is simply connected, and conversely.

Answer (score 0):

As stated the "theorem" is false:

Consider $G:=\{1<|z|<2\}$ and $f:G \to \mathbb{C}$ defined by $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$.